# Is there any way to test javascript for the Google Play Billing API other than deploying an internal release of an app via the Play console?

Tags: google-api, google-play, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a progressive web app for a client, which we will deploy via Google Play so that it can have a paid subscription feature using the Google Play Billing API.

This requires an amount of javascript to create instances of the services (Digital Goods and Billing API), list the products, trigger the purchase process, then receive the details and confirm the purchase.

These APIs are only accessible on apps that have been suitably packaged with Bubblewrap or PWABuilder and then uploaded to the Play console to be available from the Google Play store. You cannot use them from web apps, or within Visual Studio or other development environments.

So to test the javascript code, I have been doing the following:

1. Build and deploy my Blazor WASM app from Visual Studio to the web server (~ 10mins)
2. Use PWABuilder, to grab the updated app, add various settings in manually each time (check Google Billing box, select my keystore file, add in passwords and key name, etc.) then create a package to download. (~5 mins)
3. Extract the .aab file from the zip package and create a new release through the Google Play console (~3 mins)
4. Make sure my phone downloads the latest version, then go to the subscriptions page in the app to try it.

This is the best part of 20 minutes of repetitive drudgery just to find there is a bug or the javascript doesn't work. Then I need to figure out what is wrong, fix it, and then go through another 20 minutes just to test if the fix worked.

There surely must be some way to get these APIs working within Visual Studio, so I can develop properly, in a development environment? Maybe they have a sandbox mode for the APIs that does dummy purchases, that can be used freely outside of Google Play apps, just for ease of development?